# Setting a custom favicon.ico / nextJS app (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, next.js, favicon

I have a nextJS app on firebase which has been created using these commands on the terminal:

```
 % npx create-next-app@latest
 % cd myapp
 % firebase experiments:enable webframeworks
 % firebase init hosting
 % npm i react-firebase-hooks
```

I am now trying to set a customized favicon.ico for it.

But for some reasons I keep seeing the old default icon and not mine.

I assume I am not doing what is needed, but can't find why.

I replaced all the favicon.ico files that I could find with my new one, but to no avail.

What is the proper way to set a favicon.ico in this context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Next version 14, you must replace `favicon.ico` inside the `app` folder and then delete the `.next` folder to delete the cache. Finally run your application and the favicon will change, you can also perform a hard reload on the browser to make sure you clear the cahe in the browser.

Comment: I am not sure what you call a hard reload on the browser, because I tried all I could think about on that side with no success. (Including reload and removal of recent history). Any way after deleting .next it finally worked.

Comment: A hard reload is to rolead the page in the browser and delete the cache for that specific page. You can do this by pressing Cmd + Shift + R on Mac, or Ctrl + F5 on Windows.

Comment: OK. In that case I had already tried that many times.